# Find norm of functional

Tags: functional-analysis

I have:
 $$X = \left\langle\mathbb R^2, \|(x,y)\| = \sqrt{4x^2+y^2}\right\rangle$$

$$\phi : X \to \mathbb R, (x,y) \mapsto -x$$

How to find norm of this functional? And what's the norm?

Comment: Are the two questions different?

Comment: @UmbertoP. I think no, because if I know how to do it, you will be able to find the answer, so second question depends on first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\phi(x,y) = -x$, by definition the norm of $\phi$ is $$\sup_{\|(x,y)\| \le 1} |\phi(x,y)| = \sup_{\|(x,y)\| \le 1} |x|.$$
If $\sqrt{4x^2 + y^2} \le 1$, you must have $|x| \le \dfrac 12$, but equality is possible if $y = 0$. Thus $\|\phi\| = \dfrac 12$.